# Which algorithm to use to classify data by using 3 different parameters?

Tags: java, android, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, classification

I am trying to develop an android (java) project for my Artificial Intelligent thesis. It is shortly based on story reading and word quiz. One person reads a story and marks the words that he doesnt know. These words are registered to WordPortfolio db that has "Word_id", "Seen"(how many times), "Asked" (How many times asked in quiz), "Right"(how many times answered right).

I have "Words" table in my db that has 3 different parameters to make one word unique. Those are "Priority", "Level" and a specifier whether it is a Verb, Noun, Adj, Adv. etc.

What I want to ask is;

Which algorithm can I use to classify these words to ask a "word-meaning question" wisely to the learner? I want learner to see the words he had seen in story-reading part more than one to consolidate the meaning of it and also I want him to learn new words.

Comment: If I understood the question well, you need to add a tabòe "Synonyms" to your db. There you'd store the id of a word and the id a same-meaning word, and more and more same-meaning words for the same word. so you can provide alternative words to each word which apperas in the synonyms table

Comment: @Vyger No, not what i meant actually. I need an algorithm to classify word-meaning questions by using these db parameters to differentiate questions from each other with difficulty and asking-cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many types of algorithms designed to do this.  For instance, you could use a linear regression, nearest neightbor, clustering, or neural network.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_machine_learning_algorithms provides a pretty comprehinsive list of the options out there.

I would also see if your library has the book "Programming Collective Intelligence" by Toby Segaran (http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596529321.do) or something similar in your library.

Comment: Thank you, I am gonna use K-means clustering.

Answer (score 0):

classification and clustering algorithms has implemented in many artificial intelligence software's such as MATLAB,WEKA,etc. you can see a sample of this in [WEKA Text Classification for First Time & Beginner Users](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IY29uC4uem8) but i think your problem will have a good performance on MAP/REDUCE Freamework. I suggest you to use MAHOUT in your Problem which has a parallel framework and you can compromise your speed of other platforms with it.